# How to set the value of a JavaFX Spinner?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm wondering how to set the value of a JavaFX Spinner, as I haven't been able to figure it out.

I know with Swing you can just use spinner#setValue but it seems to be different with JavaFX.

```
@FXML
private Spinner<Integer> spinner;
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in addition to [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d)'s answer, an extract of the JavaDoc of the `value` attribute of the `Spinner` class:

> The value property on Spinner is a read-only property, as it is bound to the SpinnerValueFactory value property. Should the value factory change, this value property will be unbound from the old value factory and bound to the new one.
>   If developers wish to modify the value property, they may do so with code in the ollowing form:
>
> Object newValue = ...;
>   spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(newValue);